# How can I replace array(some_data) to [some_data]?

Tags: substitute

We are switching from `array()` to `[]` in our php code. And when I start to do code refactoring I found that almost all arrays are specified with `array()` and not with `[]`. How can I substitute it by `vim`?

Example:

```
// アクセスログを取る
$this->set('log_access', array(
    'target' => 'topic',
    'id'     => $id
));
```

I want to change to:

```
// アクセスログを取る
$this->set('log_access', [
    'target' => 'topic',
    'id'     => $id
]);
```

And

```
$opts    = array('http' => array('header' => 'User-Agent: iPhone-preview'));
```

I want to change to:

```
$opts    = ['http' => ['header' => 'User-Agent: iPhone-preview']];
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Certainly looks like a case for a macro

- `/array<CR>` to jump to the first array
- `qq` to record the macro into register q
- `de` to delete the word array
- `ma` to save the cursor position on the first bracket at mark a
- `%r]` to jump to the matching bracket, replace it by another bracket
- `` `ar[ `` to jump back to position a and replace that bracket
- `q` to end recording of the macro

After that, it's just repeatedly pressing `n` to jump to the next match and `@q` to play the macro. You could make the search part of the macro and just execute until it stops, but I thought you might prefer to visually check each substition... you choose :)

Comment: Interesting, +1. I was thinking using RE but discovered that's not possible: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5139300/match-parenthesised-block-using-regular-expressions-in-vim

Comment: +1 also. Just a minor possible improvement, if Vim is recent enough to support the `gn` object, you could replace `de` with `dgn` to delete the next occurrence of the last searched pattern. You could still check each substitution, but you wouldn't have to hit `n` before replaying the macro with `@q`.

Comment: Interesting suggestion, thanks. I'll just leave it like that anyways, because using  n + @q has the advantage of possibly highlighting the match, which might make the whole process go down easier. Just so many possibilities...

Comment: Yes you're right, `gn` is probably not really useful here, because the searched pattern is well-defined and not a regex whose length may vary. Plus I didn't think you could simply add the `n` motion inside the macro, your approach adds the benefit of really seeing what's going on at each step of the process.

Comment: The other good thing of adding the search to the macro could be the possibility to apply it to the whole buffer with `:% normal @a`... yes, a lot of possibilities.

Comment: A gotcha for this if you're repeating the macro across the whole file (e.g. running `999@q`), `/array` will match the PHP function `in_array` and mess up your whole day. If you want this to be something you call a lot without checking, it should look for a non-word character at the start or something.